# How to run two or more ad hoc routing protocols simultaneously in NS2?

Tags: routes, interop, adhoc

I have to run two or more ad hoc routing protocols. Can I run multiple routing protocols (e.g. AODV, DSR) on same simulator at a time?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Based on my understanding, I have edited your question.

I assume that you want to implement multiple routing protocols to evaluate their performance in various scenarios.

If you run multiple routing algorithms at a time in ad hoc, it floods the network with route request and reply packets. In ad hoc, bandwidth and energy are limited. Packet loss will increase and re-transmissions will be required.  Hence it is not recommended to run multiple algorithms. Instead log the details of algorithms individually and compare those values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to test two routing protocols (e.g. AODV and DSR) at the same time. If so, and if deploying two instances of ns-2 is not an option for you, you can try to copy ns-2 contents to an additional location and run the two identical versions of ns-2 at the same time, one for each routing protocol.

On the other hand, if what you want is to deploy the two routing protocols in the same network, It would not work well for the reasons given in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two groups of nodes, each group has 5 nodes, the first group runs AODV protocol and the second group runs DSDV, you can do it as follows.

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {icnr i}{
$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting AODV
set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
}

for {set i 5} {$i < $val(nn)} {icnr i}{
$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting DSDV
set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of running multiple protocols in one plane is a step towards interoperability between heterogeneous routing protocols. For that, I have created a Gateway node which will provide interoperability between different routing protocols to enable communication between them.
Ali thanks for your code snippet, it was very useful.